# Configure reverse DNS using Dnsmasq

Tags: networking, server, dns, dnsmasq

So I have my DNS by dnsmasq up and running. I can resolve my internal domain name but I cannot resolve the IP to my domain.
What I mean to say is I can use

```
dig rameez-ubuntu
```

and it works fine but when I use

```
dig 192.168.0.104
```

I get NXDOMAIN. I am not much of an expert in networking so please don't quote me on that. I am just trying my hands on setting my own DNS and DHCP server in this quarantine.
Can someone please help me how to I resolve the internal IP address to my domain.

Comment: Quite frankly if you don't need the power of `dig` you might want to look at `nslookup` from the package `dnsutils` (which is also one of those providing the `dig` command in the first place). I think if you're basically not interested beyond `PTR`, `A`/`AAA` and `CNAME` lookups, that's what you want. To check the lookup capabilities of your libc (as used by programs using it) you can use `getent`. The mentioned `host` utility is part of package `bind9-host` on 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing some of `dig` options do to a reverse dns request.

As specified in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig) of `dig` the `-x` allows you to use reverse lookups.

This will do the job:

`dig -x 192.168.0.104` should display `rameez-ubuntu`

You can also use `host 192.168.0.104` to get the same result.

May are you missing some configuration of DNSMasq.
As specified in the [manpage](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) of dnsmasq option
`--auth-zone=<domain>[,<subnet>[/<prefix length>]` allows to :

> Define a DNS zone for which dnsmasq acts as authoritative server.
>   Locally defined DNS records which are in the domain will be served. If
>   subnet(s) are given, A and AAAA records must be in one of the
>   specified subnets.
>
> As alternative to directly specifying the subnets, it's possible to
>   give the name of an interface, in which case the subnets implied by
>   that interface's configured addresses and netmask/prefix-length are
>   used; this is useful when using constructed DHCP ranges as the actual
>   address is dynamic and not known when configuring dnsmasq. The
>   interface addresses may be confined to only IPv6 addresses using
>   /6 or to only IPv4 using /4. This is useful when
>   an interface has dynamically determined global IPv6 addresses which
>   should appear in the zone, but RFC1918 IPv4 addresses which should
>   not. Interface-name and address-literal subnet specifications may be
>   used freely in the same --auth-zone declaration.
>
> It's possible to exclude certain IP addresses from responses. It can
>   be used, to make sure that answers contain only global routeable IP
>   addresses (by excluding loopback, RFC1918 and ULA addresses).
>
> **The subnet(s) are also used to define in-addr.arpa and ip6.arpa
>   domains which are served for reverse-DNS queries. If not specified,
>   the prefix length defaults to 24 for IPv4 and 64 for IPv6. For IPv4
>   subnets, the prefix length should be have the value 8, 16 or 24 unless
>   you are familiar with RFC 2317 and have arranged the in-addr.arpa
>   delegation accordingly. Note that if no subnets are specified, then no
>   reverse queries are answered.**

Comment: I tried both of the commands but both of them returned NXDOMAIN. do I need to configure something first for reverse lookup in dnsmasq?

Comment: I have edited my answer to add more informations that can help you